# Internet Explorer 8 and CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Quick question. What do you think, I have a few sites that use a 3 level drop-down menu that will be broken if IE8 released with its current CSS standards in IE8 beta2. So do I take the time to redo those drop downs now?  I realize that the way they rendered CSS changed completely between beta 1 and 2, but 2 was/is supposed the be a general use beta and seeing as it is the final beta you would think something as crucial as CSS rendering would have been touched up to work properly.

So what do you think, do you wait until 80% (random statistic) of ie7 users automatically update to IE8 and then worry about a broken navigation menu if it still exists. Or do you waste the time now.

... if I had it my way all web developers would just make sure that their page did not work in IE8 and then Microsoft would be forced to properly handle CSS....  But I don't usually get things my way.

Comment: Define 'properly handle' when there is no reference implementation of the CSS standard to test against ;)

Comment: There's no reference implementation, but there are clearly defined rules for each property which IE has so far followed in a quirky and haphazard manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the meta tag to force IE7 compatible rendering. Your site continues to work, no changes are made to the web site and life is happy for everyone.

That said, i'm curious about the "forced to properly handle CSS" bit; IE8 has been pretty big win for CSS standards, but I could be missing the bandwagon. ;)

HTML change necessary to force emulated IE7 rendering involves adding a meta tag immediately after the head node.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
    ...
</head>
```

Comment: I like it, heres a quick article I read about this also...  I did not know about it before. http://www.onenaught.com/posts/52/ie8-meta-switch-ie7

Answer (score 0):

Personally I find that it really depends on the audience, and the level of effort needed to fix the issue.

If I can make a quick, couple hour fix to make it compliant, even if it is for a small subset of users, great!  However, if it is much more involved, then I start to balance the potential adoption rate, the potential for Microsoft to change the behavior again, etc.

Will MS change the CSS?  I don't think anyone really knows that answer....

Answer (score 0):

I would wait until they release - maybe make a simpler version that you can quickly switch to for IE8 just in case, but don't trust anything you see in a beta version.